# Change from ob_clean to ob_end_clean?

Tags: php

The PHP documentation for readfile has an example to how to download a file:

```
<?php
$file = 'monkey.gif';

if (file_exists($file)) {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($file);
    exit;
}
?>
```

That uses ob_clean to remove the contents that may be in the output buffer.

However I have read posts (http://heap.tumblr.com/post/119127049/a-note-about-phps-output-buffer-and-readfile) that indicate that ob_end_clean should be used instead of ob_clean for large files.

My question is: what is the use of using ob_clean instead of ob_end_clean? If ob_end_clean works as ob_clean does and avoids a problem, why doesn't all documentation show using ob_end_clean instead?

Comment: The difference between them is `ob_clean` wipes the buffer then continues buffering, whereas `ob_end_clean` wipes it, then stops buffering.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`ob_clean()` flushes the buffer, but leaves output buffering active. That means your `readfile()` output will be buffered as well.

`ob_end_clean()` flushes the buffer, and TURNS OFF buffering completely, allowing `readfile()` to dump to the browser directly.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that readfile() will be buffered as well. That was the point that I had missed.

Comment: @MarcB why is there `flush()` after `ob_clean()`? Isn't `ob_clean` supposed to be `flushing` the buffer?